# Error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row in WordPress database

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1242

I am working on WordPress website

I have 1 custom table called **"wp_parent_import"** https://prnt.sc/1509bek ,
and user's data like **"user_email"** , **"user_login"** ... so on already inserted in **"wp_parent_import"** table

Now I want to insert user metadata like billing / shipping fields

So , I am joining query with wp_usermera , but it shows the error

```
UPDATE wp_parent_import

SET wp_parent_import.billing_first_name = (SELECT meta7.meta_value as billing_first_name 
                                          FROM wrd_usermeta meta7 
                                          WHERE meta7.meta_key='billing_first_name')

WHERE wp_parent_import.user_email = ( SELECT user_email 
                                    FROM wrd_users JOIN wrd_usermeta ON wrd_users.ID = 
                                     wrd_usermeta.user_id GROUP BY wrd_users.ID )
```

PS : I can't JOIN with USER ID , because user_id in **wrd_usermeta** is different , and I have inserted very few users in new table **"wp_parent_import"**

[image]

[image]

[image]

In above screenshot : Table **"wp_parent_import"** is custom , where I want few user's data and metadata
and Tables **"wrd_users"** and **"wrd_usermeta"** is in-built tables I am using for JOIN

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: Instead of = use IN clause OR make sure that your subquery should return only single row.

Comment: @amit-verma When I use IN , it still returns the same error.
like I have used : `WHERE wp_parent_import.user_email IN (SELECT  ...)`